# jQuery datatable serverside in CodeIgniter view is not as expected

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, datatable

I have new problem, from an earlier question: [jquery datatable serverside in codeigniter not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48127927/jquery-datatable-serverside-in-codeigniter-not-working)

In the **Jumlah Copy** column below I would like to see `Total : ... & Ada : ...`, but there is `Dipinjam : ...` instead.

Screenshot:
[image: not showing text : (Total : ... & Ada : ...)]

I think the problem is in the Controller:

```
$row[] = $judul->jumlah_total != 0 ? "Total : ".   anchor("buku/total/$judul->id_judul",$judul->jumlah_total) : $judul->jumlah_total.
         "<br>".
         $judul->jumlah_ada != 0 ? "Ada : ".anchor("buku/ada/$judul->id_judul",$judul->jumlah_ada) : $judul->jumlah_ada.
         "<br>".
         $judul->jumlah_dipinjam != 0 ? "Dipinjam : ".anchor("buku/dipinjam/$judul->id_judul",$judul->jumlah_dipinjam) : $judul->jumlah_dipinjam ;
```

Please help me again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding parentheses between each operator to isolate it, so each string is concatenated in the right order.

```
$row[] = ($judul->jumlah_total != 0 ? "Total : " . anchor("buku/total/$judul->id_judul",$judul->jumlah_total) : $judul->jumlah_total) .
        "<br>" .
        ($judul->jumlah_ada != 0 ? "Ada : " . anchor("buku/ada/$judul->id_judul",$judul->jumlah_ada) : $judul->jumlah_ada) .
        "<br>" .
        ($judul->jumlah_dipinjam != 0 ? "Dipinjam : " . anchor("buku/dipinjam/$judul->id_judul",$judul->jumlah_dipinjam) : $judul->jumlah_dipinjam) ;
```